# Concatenating Strings in C Implicit Definition

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I have a question regarding concatenating two strings in C to say "Ring Ding" 
I have one char * d which I malloc 14*sizeof(char) just to stay on the safe side to include the \o characters at the end, but my function is still segfaulting, and I'm not sure why. It says I cannot implicitly define strcopy. I'm thinking my problem is that I can't just come out and say "Ring", but I could be mistaken.

```
char * k = malloc(14*sizeof(char));
strcopy(k, "Ring");
strcat(k, "Ding");
printf("%s\n", k);
```

Comment: `strcopy` should be `strcpy`.  Are you sure the code is seg faulting? That's a runtime issue and I'd expect your code would fail to link, leaving you with no program to run.

Comment: just changing it from strcopy to strcpy fixed it! thanks!

Comment: If you fix the typo, the code you show should work safely without a core dump unless you've done extreme memory allocation beforehand and have run out of space.  You should check the memory allocation, but assuming that works, the rest should work OK too.  So, if the problem isn't in this code, it is probably somewhere else in your program -- so what else is your code doing?

Comment: Please update your question to show  a *complete* program that exhibits the seg fault. As @simonc says, the misspelled function name should mean that you wouldn't get an executable in the first place, so you couldn't have a seg fault. Could you be running an executable generated from an earlier version of your source code? Delete the executable before recompiling.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo for 'strcopy'; it is usually 'strcpy' from string.h

As C allows you to call functions without declaring them first, you got the warning for the 'Implicit declaration' as it was not found int string.h.

I am surprised you were able to run the program as you should have got a linker error as it could not find the definition of the function.

If you fix the typo, it should compile and run fine.

I would also recommend to use the strl* versions of these string functions (strlcpy, strlcat etc..) - it is much safer; see the man page.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the `strl*` functions are non-standard, and may not be available on all systems.

Comment: (obligatory comment about using the `strn*` family instead)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char * k = (char*)malloc(14*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(k, "Ring");
    strcat(k, "Ding");
    printf("%s\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. The `(char*)` cast is unnecessary and is poor practice. A code dump with no additional explanation is not a good answer. All you've done is add the required `#include` directives and a `main` function and fixed the mispelled function name.

Answer (score 0):

**Suppose you have:**

```
char* str1 = "Ring";
char* str2 = "Ding";
```

**Follow these steps (as a general rule):**

```
// Function 'strlen' always returns the length excluding the '\0' character at the end
// The '+1' is because you always need room for an additional '\0' character at the end
char* k = (char*)malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1);

// Write "Ring\0" into the memory pointed by 'k'
strcpy(k,str1);

// Write "Ding\0" into the memory pointed by 'k', starting from the '\0' character
strcat(k,str2);

// Print the memory pointed by 'k' until the '\0' character ("RingDing") to the console
printf("%s\n",k);

// De-allocate the memory pointed by 'k'
free(k);
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc`.